# How can I displayed the numeric result respectively in C# Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#

I'm building a C# program that allow user to click a set of numeric buttons and then display the result on the label control. For the code as below, if user click the $10, $20 and $50 buttons, the result should be displayed as $80.

[image]

But, if user would like to enter numeric buttons from "0" to "9", for example, user wants to enter "35" into the label control, user needs to enter "3" and "5" respectively. Unfortunately, the result displayed 8, not displayed as 35.

[image]

So, how can I improve this code?

From "0" to "9" numeric buttons, the click event are button_click, and the $10,$20,$50 buttons, the click event are subutton_click.

```
private decimal dollarTotal;

        public decimal DollarTotalCount
        {
            get
            {
                return dollarTotal;
            }
            set
            {
                dollarTotal = value;
                lblAmountPay.Text = "$" + dollarTotal.ToString() + ".0000";
            }
        }

private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lblAmountPay.Text == "")
            {
                lblAmountPay.Text = "$";
            }
            Button button = (Button)sender;

            DollarTotalCount = DollarTotalCount + (Convert.ToDecimal(button.Text));

        }

        private void subutton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button subButton = (Button)sender;
            DollarTotalCount = DollarTotalCount + (Convert.ToDecimal(subButton.Text.TrimStart('$')));
        }
```

Comment: From this code, the result can calculated "$28" when user entered "$20" and 8 buttons respectively.

Comment: you mean manually enter the value e.g 3+5? and it will return the value on the same label?

Comment: Yes, i hope that the label will displayed 35, when user entered 3 and 5 buttons respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Just multiply by 10 before adding the second (or third, fourth, etc) value?

```
DollarTotalCount = (DollarTotalCount * 10) + (Convert.ToDecimal(button.Text));
```